# Stationary distribution reversible for DTMC with tridiagonal transition matrix

Tags: markov-process

For a discrete-time markov chain with countable (infinite) state space S, assume it has a tridiagonal transition probability matrix. How would I be able to go about proving that any stationary distribution for this MC must be reversible (satsify detailed balance condition). Just give me a hint on how to start

Comment: Write out the equations? (definition of transition probability matrix, i.e. sum = 1 constraint; definition of stationary state, i.e. eigenvector; detailed balance equaion; all 3 constrained to tridiagonal case)